# Inbound Email Object to create (Email to Lead)

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, inboundservices

I am currently looking to implement some email to Lead functionality into an org, I am going to look to use `emailService` which hooks onto an inbound email class. Similar to [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_inbound_email.htm&type=0).

A third party site will generate the emails and send them into salesforce. Once the email comes in I need a smart way of traversing the body of the which would look something like:

```
New user registered

Name: Tom James

Position: Owner
```

And mapping the inbound information to fields in salesforce.
Just looking for direction on how to apply something like this.

Comment: You have just linked to the documentation with examples yourself...

Comment: Theres no mention of pulling information out of the body of the email and mapping it though

Comment: But there is a very similar situation in Example 2: Handle Unsubscribe Email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to define a new email service like below : -

1. create a Apex class named like "CreateRecordFrmEmail"
2. Your Name | Setup | Develop | Email Services .
3. refer the class which will be given below .

and use this class based on you logic.

```
/**
 * Email services are automated processes that use Apex classes
 * to process the contents, headers, and attachments of inbound
 * email.
 */
global class CreateRecordFrmEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email,
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

        String emailbody = email.body;//you can get email body
        String emailsubject = email.subject;//you can get email Subject
        String subToCompare = 'New user registered';

        //put you logic for your three parameters like Name, Position and subject.
        if(email.body.equalsIgnoreCase(subToCompare))
        {
            //Do your record creation or other logic.

           // Using this Save attachments, if any
            for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : email.textAttachments) {
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

                attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
                attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
                attachment.ParentId = c.Id;
                insert attachment;
            }

            //You can Binary Attachment also
            for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

                attachment.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
                attachment.Body = bAttachment.body;
                attachment.ParentId = c.Id;
                insert attachment;
            }
        }

    result.success = true;
        return result;
    }
}
```

it will solve your purpose.